# Save all inputs from the user

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an table with a column for the user input. Obviously, the table can have several rows, every row with an input for the user. Under the table I have a button for saving. My question is: if a user type in several inputs, how can I save all the inputs?
Example: my table is something like:

```
row1 -> input (user writes here: "stack")
row2 -> input (user writes here: "overflow")
saveButton
```

I want to save "stack" and also "overflow".
My code is:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8 layout-container">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceTable">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="userInput">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.rowspan]="2">Input</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="Input">
        <mat-form-field class="full-width">
          <input matInput/>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
</div>
<button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="saveInput()">Save</button>
```

Comment: can you please add your full code on stackblitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your cell like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="userInput">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.rowspan]="2">Input</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let Input">
    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="Input"/>
    </mat-form-field>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

and setup an `ngModel` on your `Input` data.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and tell you if it's working.

Comment: Not working because if you type something, will be changed in all rows.

Comment: No you're wrong in some way. I just made a a fork of another project and changed something to give you an idea. Please take a look at it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-4dwcyx?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: thank you.  I used [(ngModel)]="input", input being a variable in ts and that's why wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Formbuilder` then add the input fields.
You then add a method `onSubmit()` to process the filled form that's be called within the `<form>` tag and add a button of type submit.

You can follow the guide [here](https://angular.io/start/start-forms) for detailed steps on how to do it.